# Quickload Fails to Load Local Project Using Roswell

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

I have a project installed in `quicklisp/local-projects`, when I run `(ql:quickload "my.proj")` from SBCL (e.g., typing `sbcl` in the terminal) or from SLIME it works fine, but when I run the same code from a Roswell script it fails with:

```
debugger invoked on a QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004A58233}>:
  System "ace.test" not found
```

When I move this same project to a different folder which I track in ASDF it works. But since this project is a dependency I prefer to keep it in quicklisp's local directory.

Comment: Does it work if you initialize Quicklisp first? (the snippet that loads quicklisp/setup.lisp that you certainly have in your .sbclrc)

Comment: I'm sure you can also ask in the Lem Gitter (same developers): https://gitter.im/lem-developers/community

Comment: What's are the values of `ql:*quicklisp-home*` and `ql:*local-project-directories*` in each case?

Comment: I got this: /Users/xxxx/.roswell/lisp/quicklisp/
(/Users/xxxx/.roswell/lisp/quicklisp/local-projects/) Which now explains why it didn't find my projects. Do you know how I can set it up correctly?

Comment: @user2232305: no, I think you'd need to ask someone who understands Roswell, which I don't: sorry!